# NullReferenceException in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncServices.<ThrowAsync>b__1()

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, async-await, nullreferenceexception

I have a .NET 4.0 web project and use Microsoft.Bcl.Async to support async/await feature.
I've noticed that in production environment IIS worker process continiously crashes due to NullReferenceException which is thrown at `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncServices.<ThrowAsync>b__1()`.
It seems that the exception is thrown some place else in my code and is rethrown at `AsyncServices.ThrowAsync()` method. Unfortunately any exception details (including original stack trace) are lost so I don't know where the exception has been thrown originally.
Moreover, I've tried to catch this exception using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException events but these event are never fired.

There are all error details I have (from EventLog):

```
Exception: System.NullReferenceException

Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

StackTrace:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncServices.<ThrowAsync>b__1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

There are no obvious places in my code that may throw this exception and process crashes without any output.

How do I debug this? Are there any ways to find the source of this exception?

Comment: This might happen if you `await` a null `Task`.

Comment: Can this exception cause IIS 8.5 crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *cannot* use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` on IIS; it's [entirely unsupported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx). Sorry.

To summarize from the referenced blog post: **the behavior of async / await is undefined in ASP.NET** unless the `aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` app setting is set to `true` or the `httpRuntime.targetFramework` attribute is set to `4.5`.

And those options don't affect the ASP.NET 4 runtime.

Comment: I've migrated my project to .NET4.5 and this seems to fix the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Stephen I am getting the same issue in a Windows Service Project. All other conditions are the same. Still. Is there any way to get better StackTrace infos without updating to .Net 4.5.

Comment: @rudimenter: You could try my [AsyncDiagnostics library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncDiagnostics/).

Comment: @StephenCleary Looks like your library is only for .NET 4.5. I am running 4.0.

Comment: @rudimenter: You are correct; sorry about that. AFAIK, there's no good way to get async stack traces on .NET 4.0.